# What determines the timing of 2 event handlers firing from one event like a collision between two objects in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two objects (A and B) that collide, and when they do, they each fire the TriggerEnter2D event.

- Object A takes damage when this happens.
- Object B destroys itself.

I have noticed that in this model, the damage taken by Object A is intermittent.  Sometimes it takes damage, other times it does not.  This is due (seemingly) to Object B destroying itself before Object A counts its damage.  At least, when I comment out the Destroy method, all the damage gets counted correctly.  This is a  problem of timing, and is the kind of bug that freaks me out a bit because it's subtle.

Since I'm new to Unity, is there a best practice on handling the architecture of two interacting objects like this?  This must be a very common case.  The tutorials I've seen seem to use publicly exposed properties of the other object (say object A) from within the handling object (object B).

Thus, I would have only one handler on Object B that would then call a public method on Object A to say "you were damaged".  Is this best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your object A is a player and object B is a bullet of some sort, it's better to define a public function to make object A take damage which is dependent on object B, rather than calling collision handlers independently.

```
public class ObjectB : MonoBehaviour {
    public int dmg = 10;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<SCRIPT>().TakeDamage(dmg);
            destroy(gameobject);
        }
    }
}
```

I am too early in the game development journey of mine to state 'best practices', but for the first few projects following various sources, this was how collision was handled: handle collision on the secondary object by calling a public effector function on main object.

Comment: yes, this is in-line with the tutorials I've seen.  I'll see if anyone else has a different opinion, but looks like this is it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

gregory you can use the destroy function with a second argument which is the time delay to delete the object for eg : Destroy(GameObject,TimeToDelete(in float));

that way  both on trigger events shuld work. Otherwise what Varaquilex said is a better way and you should mark it as answered .

Comment: I would want to use a process that would guarantee behaviour as a best practice.  Thanks tho.